# Can you share save files on Steam Family Share to other accounts?

Tags: steam, achievements, steam-family-sharing, steam-cloud

I've been playing on my brother's Steam account for a long time and it's about time I should get my own Steam account now, but looking up the Family Share it keeps saying that everyone will have their own save files. So is it possible that I can have my old save files from my brother's account to my new one? Or do I have to restart all of my games from the beginning?

Comment: That depends on the games in question and where they store their save files, It would help to know what game(s) you want to copy over to your new account.

Comment: @dly Are there games that support sharing saved games over different accounts?

Comment: @Joachim when the savegames are file based they can just be copied over to the new profile. This works pretty well for older games.

Comment: @dly Yes, but they all do, right? "Depends on the game" reads as though there are other ways beside that, so I was wondering.

Comment: @Joachim no, not all of them. Some are cloud based and tied to the account and copying them over is different, if even possible. Others can be file based and encrypted and tied to the account at the same time.

Comment: @dly the game im trying to move save files is Monster Hunter Stories 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm unsure whether it's possible to directly transfer one steam cloud to another, it's possible to do so in your local files.

There are two occasions where the steam cloud synchronizes with the local files on the computer:

- Whenever a game is launched, the steam cloud is downloaded so that the local files are up to date with any other systems you've played on
- Whenever a game is closed, the local files are uploaded into the steam cloud so that other systems will be able to access the new saves you created.

In short, if you want to transfer the save data from your brother's account into yours, here's what you should do:

1. Find where the saves are stored for his account on your computer, this can vary a lot between games.
2. Copy those files to where saves are stored for your account
3. The next time you launch and close that game with your account, those files will be uploaded into your steam account.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to transfer saved games from one account to the other that is officially supported by Steam. Copying the save files manually seems to be the right answer.